# How to fetch Data from mysql database into android

Tags: php, android, json

I have an android application that contains 2 pages, one for login and the other for a list view.

The Login is good and when the PHP JSON result is good in the web but I can't view my items in the listview when I click on the button an error appears "Unfortunately the app has stopped " and application restart.

> this is the PHP code :

```
<?php
    include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {

     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows >0) {


     while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     $tem = $row;

     $json = json_encode($tem);


     }

    } else {
     echo "No Results Found.";
    }
     echo $json;
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

For the android:

> MainPageActivity.java

```
package com.example.dell.apptest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    String url="http://187.241.2.32:8089/AppTest/JSonTextView.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        final Downloader d=new Downloader(this,url,lv);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //EXECUTE DOWNLOAD
                d.execute();
            }
        });
    }



}
```

It gives this JSON :

```
[{"Id":"7","Name":" test","Position":"description"},{"Id":"1","Name":"zerty","Position":"feztez"}]
```

> Parser.java

```
package com.example.dell.apptest;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Integer> {

    Context c;
    ListView lv;
    String data;

    ArrayList<String> products=new ArrayList<>();
    ProgressDialog pd;

    public Parser(Context c, String data, ListView lv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.data = data;
        this.lv = lv;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("Parser");
        pd.setMessage("Parsing ....Please wait");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return this.parse();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);

        if(integer == 1)
        {
            //ADAPTER
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(c,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,products);

            //ADAPT TO LISTVIEW
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            //LISTENET
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Snackbar.make(view,products.get(position),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
                }
            });

        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to Parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        pd.dismiss();
    }

    //PARSE RECEIVED DATA
    private int parse()
    {
        try
        {
            //ADD THAT DATA TO JSON ARRAY FIRST
            JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(data);

            //CREATE JO OBJ TO HOLD A SINGLE ITEM
            JSONObject jo=null;

            products.clear();

            //LOOP THRU ARRAY
            for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
            {
                jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

                //RETRIOEVE NAME
                String name=jo.getString("Name");

                //ADD IT TO OUR ARRAYLIST
                products.add(name);
            }

            return 1;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

> Downloader.java

```
   package com.example.dell.apptest;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String> {

    Context c;
    String address;
    ListView lv;

    ProgressDialog pd;

    public Downloader(Context c, String address, ListView lv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.address = address;
        this.lv = lv;
    }

    //B4 JOB STARTS
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("Fetch Data");
        pd.setMessage("Fetching Data...Please wait");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String data=downloadData();
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        pd.dismiss();;

        if(s != null)
        {
            Parser p=new Parser(c,s,lv);
            p.execute();

        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to download data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private String downloadData()
    {
        //connect and get a stream
        InputStream is=null;
        String line =null;

        try {
            URL url=new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            is=new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();

            if(br != null) {

                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }

            }else {
                return null;
            }

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(is != null)
            {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check your logs. What data you are receiving from the api.

Comment: I can't see what is the problem